# Combining elements of a given set of items in z3

Tags: z3, linear-programming, smt

The following z3 code picks elements from `{x1..x6}` in order to maximize the total weight, while satisfying total length less than 10.

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Item (mk-item (size Int) (weight Int)))))

(define-fun ee () Item (mk-item 0 0)); empty item
(define-fun i1 () Item (mk-item 4 2))
(define-fun i2 () Item (mk-item 4 2))
(define-fun i3 () Item (mk-item 1 4))
(define-fun i4 () Item (mk-item 5 5))
(define-fun i5 () Item (mk-item 3 2))
(define-fun i6 () Item (mk-item 1 9))

(define-fun x_props ((x Bool) (i Item)) Item (ite x i ee))

; each x defines whether an item is selected or not
(declare-const x1 Bool)
(declare-const x2 Bool)
(declare-const x3 Bool)
(declare-const x4 Bool)
(declare-const x5 Bool)
(declare-const x6 Bool)

(define-fun total_size () Int
  (+
    (size (x_props x1 i1))
    (size (x_props x2 i2))
    (size (x_props x3 i3))
    (size (x_props x4 i4))
    (size (x_props x5 i5))
    (size (x_props x6 i6))
  ))

(define-fun total_weight () Int
  (+
    (weight (x_props x1 i1))
    (weight (x_props x2 i2))
    (weight (x_props x3 i3))
    (weight (x_props x4 i4))
    (weight (x_props x5 i5))
    (weight (x_props x6 i6))
  ))

(assert (< total_size 10))
(maximize total_weight)

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

However, I can imagine this scaling very bad as the number of item properties explode, and the number of items as well.

Would there be a different, more concise approach? In particular, can you think of a way to factorize the `total_size` and `total_weight` functions, as there is a lot of repetition there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with your encoding. Since you need to sum through a number of elements, the only way to do that is either being explicit about them, or use a recursive function. While SMT-Lib and Z3 both support recursive-functions, the implementation isn't quite strong yet, and you'd better stick to the explicit style.

The issue here is really trying to use SMT-Lib as a programming language, which it was not really intended for. I'd recommend looking into high-level language interfaces instead, such as those from Python, Scala, or Haskell; which would take care of the repetitive coding. Here's a good site for describing how to do model such things in Python: https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm and here's an example of a similar problem in Haskell: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-7.4/docs/src/Data.SBV.Examples.Optimization.VM.html